# regex, exclude "," from matched strings

Tags: regex

Hello straight to the point:
I have this regex:

[image: Regex]

You can see regex `(?:-|role:)??\binfo-ansible[\s|,]`
I'm trying to match all strings in this case "info-ansible" with rules:

- It has to start by "- " or "role: " (example: role: info-ansible)
- It has to end either by white-space or ","

Those rules are already implemented into regex

In the very first match you can see it matched `info-ansible,`
I dont want "," to be included in the match.

Seems to be like very simple problem but i spent so much time on it already.

The is link to online regex tool with those texts already in: https://regex101.com/r/Xixz3O/3

Comment: `(?:-|role:)?\binfo-ansible(?=[\s,])`? See https://regex101.com/r/9oJCYu/1

Comment: @WiktorStribizew Comments should be for improving the question, not answering it. With a brief explanation of what you're suggesting, that would make a good answer.

Comment: Depending on the context you might also use a word-boundary `\b` or just nothing at all, if there are no other elements of which `info-ansible` is a prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [positive lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) on the `whitespace|comma` capture;

So instead of `[\s|,]` use `(?=[\s,])`

```regex
(?:-|role:)??\binfo-ansible(?=[\s,])
```

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/Xixz3O/4)

---

Simplified (Thx [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810812/regex-exclude-from-matched-strings/63810891?noredirect=1#comment112837820_63810891));

```
(?:-|role:)?\binfo-ansible(?=[\s,])
```

Comment: Note the lazy `??` quantifier in `(?:-|role:)??` will work the same way as with a greedy `?`, as the string is read from left to right, and if there is `-` or `role:`, they will get consumed anyway.

Comment: Glad it worked, please note (as @WiktorStribiżew said) the first `??` could be avoided!